# npm fundation не работает

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

пытаюсь запустить `npm run build` но выдает ошибки, в чем может быть дело?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не хватает зависимости gulp-sass

Comment: пробую так npm i gulp-cli -g но ошбок еще больше

Comment: что у Вас в package.json